# Issue regarding flames game in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, parameter

I am trying to make a flames game in shell script. I take 2 names and sort names.
My code like this:

```bash
var=$(j=1;for((i=0;i<${#name1Low};i++));do echo "${name1Low:i:j}";done |sort|tr -d '\n') #sorted name1
var1=$(j=1;for((k=0;k<${#name2Low};k++));do echo "${name2Low:k:j}";done |sort|tr -d '\n') #sorted name2
```

To make it all lower I do this

```bash
if [[ $name1 =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ && $name2 =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]
then
    name1Low=$(echo $name1 | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]')
    name2Low=$(echo $name2 | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]')
fi
```

And to remove the same characters I do this :

```shell
var2=$(diff <(fold -w1 <<< "$var") <(fold -w1 <<< "$var1")| awk '/[<>]/{printf $2}') #checking for differernt characters using diff and folding using fold to newline after every 1 character (fold -w1)
```

Now the actual problem I am facing is in the `flames` part. I am running a loop to check for the length of the different sting and at that position or iteration whatever character is there to remove it from this:

```bash
flames()
{
    echo "$word ${#word}"
    size=`echo ${#var2}`
    
    for((i=0;i<${#word};i++))
    do
        echo  " ${word:$i:1}"

        if [[ $i == $size ]]
        then
            cha=`echo ${word:$i:1}`
            word1=`echo ${word//$cha/}`
        fi
    done
    
    word=`echo $word1`
    echo "$word ${#word}"
}
```

What its doing is its working till the value of size is equal to the `i` value . After that I am unable to understand how to check for and remove till there is just one character left?

```bash
while [ ${#word} -ne 1 ]
do
    flames
done
```

The above portion is running infinitely . Also is there any other way to doing it better than actually doing the parameter expansion?

Comment: Is there a reason for using ````word=`echo $word1```` instead of ````word="$word1"````? I knew UUOC (useless use of cat), but UUOS (useless use of subshell) is new.

Comment: And to lowercase, you can just use `name1Low=${name1Low,,}`

Comment: @bakunin [Useless use of echo](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#echo) is also a thing, among some others.

Comment: Process substitution (`<()`) and here strings (`<<<`) are bashisms. I suggest tagging the question as related to Bash.

Comment: @Vilinkameni: sorry, but process substitution is also available in ksh (in fact it was invented there), in the rc-shell and generally in Version 10 UNIX (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution). It is a common misconception that it is a bashism

Comment: In any case, those two features are not part of the POSIX standard, so the question should be tagged appropriately.

Comment: Your `while` loop should break when the length of `$word` is just a single character. You've not shared an example run - does the length reduce at all? If so at what point does it get stuck?

Comment: In the `flames()` function, I can see where `$var2` was set in your example code, but where did `$word` come from? It seems to me that the reason your `while` loop never exits is because `$word` is unset, so the length is zero

Comment: This question could benefit from a more clear description of what is the desired output with given input, and making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (Not taking into account a number of common pitfalls when writing shell scripts, such as backticks, etc - OP should try checking the code in shellcheck or on [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/).)